# Python OUTPUT 234432?

Tags: python, recursion

Could someone please explain this block of code. I understand it going upto 4 (num(n+1)) but why does the second print statement minus from 4 and it loops back in the if statement that has n+1?.

```
def num(n):
    print(n)
    if n < 4:
        num(n+1)
    print(n)

num(2)
```

The output to the above is `234432`

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python recursion introduction", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Or run it with an online visual debugger and you'll see exactly what's happening, this one demonstrates it perfectly http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: Try getting out a pen and paper and physically writing out each step. It won't take long and you'll understand the code deeply.

Comment: Hi all thanks for your replies. I was just confused with the second print statement that would start with n=4 . Maybe because my starting point at the beginning of the program began with 2 it loops back to it. I'm new to recursion so ill watch a few videos and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't 'go backwards', the first print() is called 3 times, then the second print is called 3 times.

The program flow could be represented as follows:

```
num(2):
    print(2)
    num(3):
        print(3)
        num(4):
           print(4)
           print(4)
        print(3)
    print(2)
```

It's tricky to represent recursion with words or pictures, suggest you run it through step-by-step, either on paper or with some visualisation tool.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that the arguments are different for each call. Thus in `num(4)` `n` is `4` for the whole duration of `num` regardsless if `num` is called with `3` as argument in the middle of it. It will have it's `n` being `3` for the whole duration of the call.

So `num` does 2 things in order when `n` is 4 or higher: print `n`, then print `n`. eg.

```
num(4) // prints 44
```

So `num` does 3 things in order when `n` is 3 or less: print `n`, call `num(n+1)`, print `n`. eg.

```
num(3) // prints 3443 since num(4) happens to print 44 and it is called between printing 3s
```

`num(2)` is just the same as `3` but it calls `num(3)` in between which prints `3443` in between the two print calls.

You can think of this that each call returns back to the callee when finished and it does not treat recursion any special. When they return the function that called will continue and the called function will not have affected the local values even when it is called the same or it is the same function that is called.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. That is much clearer to me now.